# Removing a hidden Windows 10 account

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, user-accounts, sysprep

Bit of an odd one, this. I'm attempting to sysprep my Windows 10 machine, after using remove-appxprovisionedpackage and remove-appxpackage scripts to get rid of bloat.

However, I'm getting an error from sysprep that's suggesting that one of the appx provisions is associated with an account that no longer exists. The SID still exists, but the account was deleted after initial setup.

I have run the remove-appxpackage command with the -AllUsers switch, and that still hasn't fixed it, so I'm at a bit of a loss as to what the solution to this issue is.

Any help would be appreciated, feel free to ask for more information.